# Page Expired issue on IE with multipart/form-data form

Tags: internet-explorer, jsp, file-upload, back-button, multipartform-data

I have a "Page Expired" issue on IE if I specify the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag.

By simplifying, I have 3 JSP pages `page1.jsp`, `page2.jsp` and `page3.jsp`.

`page1.jsp` (which contains a form with `enctype="multipart/form-data"`) submits to `page2.jsp` and `page2.jsp` submits to `page3.jsp`.

If I:

1. submit to page2.jsp
2. submit again from page2.jsp to page3.jsp
3. go back from page3.jsp to page2.jsp (using history.back() javascript), I get "Page Expired".

I read about cache-control, but setting these page with cache-control private or public doesn't change the situation

```
// page1.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="page2.jsp">
File to upload: <input type=file name=upfile>
<input type=submit value="Go to page2"> 
</form>
```

```
 // page2.jsp
<html>
<head>  
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="page3.jsp">            
   <input type=submit value="Go to page3"> 
   </form> 
 </body>
</html>


// page3.jsp
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="end.jsp">
    <input type="button" value="Go to page 2" onclick="javascript:history.back();"> 
    <input type=submit value="Go to end">        
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use post-redirect-get paradigm:

1. page1 -- post --> servlet1
2. servlet1 -- process data then redirects --> page2
3. page2 -- post --> servlet2
4. servlet2 -- process data then redirects --> page3

this way, browsers will not ask to re-submit or display "page expired" on back pressed

however you can reduce the number of pages/servlets implementing this way:

page2.jsp

```
<% 
    if("POST".equals(request.getMethod()) 
    {
        // process submitted params/files
        response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI()); // redirect to the same page
    }
%>
<html>
    blah blah blah
</html>
```

or you can simply use ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a form on page 2 you click to go to page 3, you should use

```
<%
  response.sendRedirect("page3.jsp");
  return;
%>
```

on page 2 in JSP after the upload processing is done.

You get your "page expired" message when you go back to page 2 from page 3 which you shouldn't be doing nor allowing to be done.  If page2 is the code handling the file upload, you MUST do a redirect from there, which will prevent being able to use the back button to get back to page 2.

Why do you want to do this?  Because pages that perform update operations on the server (database update, file upload processing) should always redirect to another page to prevent back button double submission or refresh double submission problems.  (Doing the redirect means, the back button will take you back to page 1 rather than page 2. Page 2 will be skipped in the history.)

The browser itself is giving you some level of protection against double file upload by expiring the upload processing page, but you shouldn't be relying on that, because the browser will not do that for normal form submissions, only for file uploads (i.e. multipart/form-data).

Comment: first of all the file upload is on page1. Here, I'm simplifying: on page1, I've a form with some fields (and file upload), on the page2 I've another form with some fields (without file upload), on page3 I've a summary of user data input and when the user submits page3 form, an insert is executed with a redirect to another page to prevent form resubmission

Comment: still, you need to do a server-side redirect on the page handling the upload, so you need more than 3 pages then, you need 4 (or more)

Comment: "first of all the file upload is on page1" You mean the form for it is on page1 but its processed on page2, right?  That's the problem. Page2 needs to do a server-side redirect after processing the upload.

Comment: Yes. When the user submits the form on page1, a servlet loads the file in a temp dir and page2 is displayed. Then the user submits the form on page2, a second servlet is called and the page3 is displayed. The issue arises coming back from page3 to page2 (only on IE)

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you get is correct. When you do a return to page2, the data stands to be resubmitted and since that does not happen, the page is shown as expired. You can check this behavior using some other browsers such as Firefox or Google Chrome, it will ask you if you want to resubmit the data.

If you want to got to page2 after the page3 you will need to redirect from page3 to page2 instead of a return using the history actions.

Comment: it doesn't happen with Firefox ang Chrome. Morevover, without the file upload on page1, it doesn't happen on IE too.